# How to Move an HTML Element after another element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use Javascript or Jquery to move a div to a different place in the DOM tree. for example, I need to move shopByType after ShopBycolor. I tried append and insertbefore with no luck.

```
<form id="filter_form">
    <div class="Block ShopByColor Moveable Panel" id="ShopByType">
    <div class="Block ShopByColor Moveable Panel" id="ShopBySize">
    <div class="Block ShopByColor Moveable Panel" id="ShopByColor">
    <div class="Block ShopByColor Moveable Panel" id="ShopByGender">
</form>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your JS/jQuery that shows your best attempt to resolve this yourself.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 1):

you can use use `insertAfter()` as follows:

```js
let shopType = $("#ShopByType");
let shopColor = $("#ShopByColor");

shopType.insertAfter(shopColor);
```

```html
<form id="filter_form">
  <div class="Block ShopByColor Moveable Panel" id="ShopByType">ShopByType</div>
  <div class="Block ShopByColor Moveable Panel" id="ShopBySize">ShopBySize</div>
  <div class="Block ShopByColor Moveable Panel" id="ShopByColor">ShopByColor</div>
  <div class="Block ShopByColor Moveable Panel" id="ShopByGender">ShopByGender</div>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The first one doesn't seem quite right.